# What can cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java

My code compiles fine, but I'm gettting a runtime error on this line:

`File myFile = new File(FilenameUtils.concat(basePath, localPath));`

The error thrown is:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils`

Why would the code compile if it can't resolve a class?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should add commons-io library to your runtime classpath.

http://commons.apache.org/io/

In NetBeans Project Properties Window, you click **Libraries** in the left panel, and in the right panel are 4 categories of classpath you can configure. You should update your **Run** path or make sure **Compile** contains commons-io library.

Comment: ok, im new to java - how do i add it to the runtime path? im using netbeans, thanks

Comment: In NetBeans Project Properties Window, you click Libraries  in the left panel, and in the right panel are 4 categories of classpath you can configure. You should update your Run path or make sure Compile contains commons-io library.

Comment: @uthark: you should edit your answer, it'll be be more useful :)

Comment: @Valentin Rocher Actually my answer answers the question. Original post doesn't contain anything about netbeans.

Comment: yeah yeah, I know, that was just in order to help, +1ed anyway ;)

Answer (score 3):

Check this out [from the NetBeans tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/tools/netbeans_part1/#importing)

Basically, you are going to add a JAR file (a library, the commons.apache.org IO one) to your project "properties" classpath.

If you were to run your packaged project from the command line, you could specify classpath like this:

```
java -cp apache-io.jar myproject.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have the jar in your developen environment classpath, but you need it in your runtime classpath

Comment: as above, how do i add it to the runtime path? im using netbeans, thanks

Comment: I do not know how is in netbeans, but make an ear and put all jars (yours and the dependencies) inside.